# AND-gate transistor structure

Tags: digital-logic

I have some questions about the AND-gate which is made by two transistors in this picture below.

1. When input A or B or both are open (z) the output is '0' by default; is it right?
2. When input A and B are '1', two transistors drive '1' to output so it is conflict because '0' and '1' are driven to output. But according to the truth table, the output is 1 when A & B are '1'. This is ambiguous for me. Please explain about it.

[image: schematic]

Comment: The "2" part is unclear. What conflict?

Comment: ground is driving '0' to output permanently. and then two transistors drive '1' to output. so i thing it is conflict. please explain about it.

Comment: That's why there is a resistor down there. To "separate" between `0` and `1`.

Comment: can you explain more about this resistor?

Comment: In case of `1 & 1` there will be a voltage drop on the resistor and the resulting current according to Ohm's law.

Comment: @sadeghyeganehzadeh - An easy way to think of it is that a resistor provides a weak coupling to voltage level, and a transistor provides a strong coupling (when it is active).  Therefore the output from the transistors overrides the default provided by the resistor.  If you've looked into VHDL at all, compare the difference between  `0`, `1`, `L`, and `H` as std_logic values.  The resistor gives an output of `L`, while the transistors when activated give outputs of `1`.

Answer (score 0):

First consider that floating inputs are not considered good design practice.  And such a configuration leads to unexpected results.  Some implementations of [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic) get around this by including input pull down or pull up resistors.  However your example has neither.

Here is a circuit similar to the one in your question:

[image]

As most logic gate transistor circuits are designed to operate in saturation, we will assume that is the case here.  One can then say the transistor is like a switch.  On when the base senses a logic 1 (high voltage) and off when the base senses a logic 0 (ground).

At this point we note that if either transistor is off the output is pulled to ground or a logic 0 by the output pull down resistor.  Only when both transistors are on do they complete the circuit to high voltage and over power the output's pull down resistor driving the output to logic 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand in depth how a bjt (or any other type of transistor) is working you have to study electric circuits and microelectronics. Now to answer your question:

Consider the two bjts as on/off switches - this means that they work at saturation or cut-off regions and not in forward active region. If the base pin of the bjt is low, then the switch is off. Obviously, when the base pin is high the switch is on.

So, when none or one switch is on, there is no current flow, hence the voltage drop in the resistor R2 is 0. When both switches are on, there is a current flow, with magnitude equal to

I = (Vcc - 2*Vce,sat)/R2

So the output, which is parallel to R2, has a voltage potential of

Vout = Vcc - 2*Vce,sat

which you can consider as high.

Answer (score 0):

When either inputs is low, you don't get any current, so output voltage will be grounded, Vout=R2*I=R2*0=0V.

Now consider both inputs A and B are high. In this case, assuming base drive resistors R is chosen appropriately, both transistors will be in the saturation region, with an ideally 0 volts across their CE. The output voltage then will be roughly Vcc, if we neglect Vce(sat) of transistors.